# Setting a custom prompt in GHCI leads to lots of error messages on standard types

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghci

I'm currently learning some Haskell using hdevtools via ALE in Vim. It appears that setting a custom GHCI prompt leads hdevtools to report errors even on trivial type declarations.

My `.ghci` file consists of only the custom prompt:

```
:set prompt "λ> "
```

With that this snippet...

```
hello :: String
hello = "Hello world"
```

...is highlighted as an error:

```
[hdevtools] Not in scope: type constructor or class ‘String’ [Error]
```

This really is caused by the custom prompt, turning it off removes the error message. It seems that [others](https://github.com/data61/fp-course/issues/79) have had the same problem, but didn't really give a solution. I would obviously like to keep using both the custom prompt and hdevtools, so what is the intended way here to make this work?

(Versions are 8.6.3 for GHC and 0.1.8.0 for hdevtools.)

Comment: The editor, Vim in your case, queries the backend parser by analyzing the strings returned by the backend, looking for any error messages. Unless you want to re-write the editor package, don't change the prompt string.

Comment: I know that I could simply stop using one or the other, but GHCI and hdevtools are two the most widely used Haskell development tools out there, surely there must be a way to get them to work together, especially on something as simple as a custom prompt string, right?

Comment: As I said, you will have to re-write the ALE code to not choke on the changed prompt. When you have a good, working solution, you can submit the change to the ALE developers.

Comment: Maybe you can configure `hdevtools to pass [--ignore-dot-ghci](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#ghc-flag--ignore-dot-ghci) to ghci?  I haven't tried this, and it's too coarse if you have other config in .ghci.

Comment: @bergey That seems to be the best solution for now, thanks for the tip!